# Datetime timezone adjustments

Tags: c#, date

My database is located in e.g. california.
My user table has all the user's timezone e.g. -0700 UTC

How can I adjust the time from my database server whenever I display a date to the user who lives in e.g. new york? UTC/GMT -4 hours

Answer (score 4):

You should store your data in UTC format and showing it in local timezone format.

```
DateTime.ToUniversalTime() -> server;
DateTime.ToLocalTime() -> client
```

You can adjust date/time using AddXXX methods group, but it can be error prone. .NET has support for time zones in [System.TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

If you use .Net, you can use `TimeZoneInfo`. Since you tagged the question with 'c#', I'll assume you do.

The first step is getting the `TimeZoneInfo` for the time zone in want to convert to. In your example, NY's time zone. Here's a way you can do it:

```
//This will get EST time zone
TimeZoneInfo clientTimeZone
    = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

//This will get the local time zone, might be useful
// if your application is a fat client
TimeZoneInfo clientTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
```

Then, after you read a `DateTime` from your DB, you need to make sure its `Kind` is correctly set. Supposing the `DateTime`'s in the DB are in UTC (by the way, that's usually recommended), you can prepare it to be converted like this:

```
DateTime aDateTime = dataBaseSource.ReadADateTime();
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(aDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Finally, in order to convert to a different time zone, simply do this:

```
DateTime clientTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDateTime, clientTimeZone);
```

Some extra remarks:

- `TimeZoneInfo` can be stored in static fields, if you are only interested in a few specific time zones;
- `TimeZoneInfo` store information about daylight saving. So, you wouldn't have to worry about that;
- If your application is web, finding out in which time zone your client is in might be hard. One way is explained here: http://kohari.org/2009/06/15/automagic-time-localization/

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Up until .NET 3.5 (VS 2008), .NET does not have any built-in support for timezones, apart from converting to and from UTC.

If the time difference is always exactly 3 hours all year long (summer and winter), simply use **`yourDate.AddHours(3)`** to change it one way, and **`yourDate.AddHours(-3)`** to change it back. Be sure to factor this out into a function explaining the reason for adding/substracting these 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() and then use the TimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset property to offset the time in the database based on the offset difference

Info on System.TimeZoneInfo [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo_members.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You know, this is a good question.  This year I've done my first DB application and as my input data related to time is an Int64 value, that is what I stored off in the DB.  My client applications retrieve it and do DateTime.FromUTC() or FromFileTimeUTC() on that value and do a .LocalTime() to show things in their local time.  I've wondered whether this was good/bad/terrible but it has worked well enough for my needs thus far.  Of course the work ends up being done by a data access layer library I wrote and not in the DB itself.

Seems to work well enough, but I trust others who have more experience with this sort of thing could point out where this is not the best approach.

Good Luck!